# How to transform a SQL query to Eloquent

Tags: mysql, eloquent

I have a "simple" SQL I want as an Eloquent query. I need to use the "next_training" in a further SQL query.

My SQL:

```
SELECT u.id, ce.day, ce.created, (SELECT `day` as d FROM `programs_days` pd WHERE pd.program_id = u.current_program AND exercise_id IS NOT NULL AND pd.day > ce.day LIMIT 1) next_training_day
FROM users u
INNER JOIN users_completed_exercises ce ON ce.user_id = u.id
WHERE ce.created > '2021-03-16'
```

This is my eloquent attempt

```
$query = User::whereNotNull('current_program')
                    ->join('users_completed_exercises', 'users.id', '=', 'users_completed_exercises.user_id')
                    ->whereDate('users_completed_exercises.created', '>', date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-3 day')));

                $query = $query->addSelect(['next_training' => function($q) {
                    $q->select('day')
                        ->from('programs_days')
                        ->whereColumn('program_id', 'users.current_program')
                        ->whereNotNull('programs_days.exercise_id')
                        ->whereRaw('programs_days.day > users_completed_exercises.day')
                        ->limit(1);
                }]);
```

I get an error::

Syntax error: near 'from `users` inner join `users_completed_exercises` on `users`.`id` = `users_com' at line 1 (SQL: select  from` users`inner join`users_completed_exercises`on`users`.`id`=`users_completed_exercises`.`user_id`where`current_program `is not null and date(`users_completed_exercises`.`created`) > 2021-03-16)

Comment: What is the error? Because what you post after _"I get an error"_ looks like a query to me, not an error. If the query is *wrong*, then explicitly point out what is wrong.

Comment: of course - I have updated the "bottom" of the question.